# NumPy - formatting two arrays to one multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following values:

```
grade_list = [[99 73 97 98] [98 71 70 99]]
excercise_list = ['1' '2']
```

Using Numpy, I want to convert it to one multidimensional array to have the average grade for each exercise (the first item in grade_list refers to the exercise number 1)

The output should look like this: `[[1. 2.] [91.75 84.5]]`

Which means Avg. grade for exercise #1 - 91.75, and 84.5 for #2.

How I can convert it using numpy? I have read about [NumPy axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) parameter but not sure how to put it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis 0 is the first nesting level (the two lists), axis 1 is the second level (four grades per entry in axis 0). You want to compute the mean along axis 1, so that axis 0 remains. So the mean grades are

`mean_grades = np.mean(grade_list, axis=1)`.

Then you stack the two lists in another nested list, wrap that in a numpy array and set the type to float (your excercises are strings):

`result = np.array([excercise_list, mean_grades]).astype(float)`.

Comment: Wow thanks! Assuming my excercises are `int`, I can skip the `astype` call?

Comment: Yes. Integers can be represented as floats, so numpy will convert everything to floats. Strings can not always be represented as numbers, so you explicitly have to tell numpy that it shall try to convert to float, using `astype(float)`.